# Помогите написать селектор jsoup

Tags: java, select, jsoup

Есть вот такой кусок вебкода. Нужно выбрать `4591077`.

```
<div class="story" data-story-id="4591077" data-visited="false" data-story-long="false">
```

В этом месте нужно выбрать `2 ноября 2016 в 23:58`.

```
<div class="story__date" title="2 ноября 2016 в 23:58">7 дней назад</div>
```

Никак не могу разобраться. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `attr(...)`, который по названию атрибута возвращает его значение:

Первое:

```
Document page = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"story\" data-story-id=\"4591077\" data-visited=\"false\" data-story-long=\"false\">");
int dataStoryId = Integer.parseInt(page.select("div.story").attr("data-story-id"));
```

Второе:

```
Document page = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"story__date\" title=\"2 ноября 2016 в 23:58\">7 дней назад</div>");
String title = page.select("div.story__date").attr("title");
```

Comment: Благодарю, мучился два дня с этим

Comment: Все понял спасибо